# Turning a fixed length Vec<u8> of hex only chars into an int

Tags: rust

How do I turn a fixed length `Vec<u8>` of hex chars into a `u32`?

```
let input: Vec<u8> = vec!['b','e','e','f']; // Pretend this works
let output: u32 = // Do some magic (Probably with serialize)
assert!(0xbeef == output);
```

Comment: You state you have a vector of "hex chars", but your type annotation is of `u8`. These are not the same thing! A `char` (with single quotes) can hold any single Unicode codepoint, which takes more than 8 bits. Which do you have?

Comment: I have a vector of `u8`s limited to the codepoints `0` through `9`, `a` through `f` and `A` through `F` - sorry for the confusion I still think in C when it comes to... Anything involving strings or bytes :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may not be the most efficient way, but may be the most obvious. Start by turning your bytes into a string, then convert that string to a number:

**Rust 1.0**

```
fn main() {
    let input: Vec<u8> = b"beef"[..].to_owned();
    let s = String::from_utf8(input).unwrap();
    let v = u32::from_str_radix(&s, 16).unwrap();
    println!("{:x}", v);
    assert!(0xbeef == v);
}
```

**Original**

```
use std::num;

fn main() {
    let input: Vec<u8> = vec!['b' as u8, 'e' as u8, 'e' as u8, 'f' as u8];
    let s = String::from_utf8(input).unwrap();
    let v: u32 = num::from_str_radix(&*s, 16).unwrap();
    println!("{:x}", v);
    assert!(0xbeef == v);
}
```

> Is there a way to do this with `serialize`?

Not that I'm aware of. Serialize has [`FromHex`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/serialize/hex/trait.FromHex.html) which converts a `&str` to a `Vec<u8>`. Then you'd still have to convert those bytes into a number somehow:

```
extern crate serialize;
use serialize::hex::FromHex;

fn main() {
    let input: Vec<u8> = vec!['b' as u8, 'e' as u8, 'e' as u8, 'f' as u8];
    let s = String::from_utf8(input).unwrap();
    let bytes: Vec<u8> = s.from_hex().unwrap();

    let v = bytes.into_iter().fold(0u32, |val, byte| val << 8 | byte as u32);

    println!("{:x}", v);
    assert!(0xbeef == v);
}
```

At that point, it's probably easier to convert directly from codepoint to number and do the summation yourself:

```
fn dehex(c: u8) -> u8 {
    match c {
        b'0'...b'9' => c - b'0',
        b'a'...b'f' => c - b'a' + 10,
        b'A'...b'F' => c - b'A' + 10,
        _ => panic!("Do something better here"),
    }
}

fn main() {
    let input: Vec<u8> = vec![b'b', b'e', b'e', b'f'];
    let v = input.into_iter().fold(0u32, |val, char| (val << 4) | dehex(char) as u32);
    println!("{:x}", v);
    assert!(0xbeef == v);
}
```

Comment: Isn't there a way to do this with `serialize`?